# Is it possible to make asynchronous connections with Zend_Http?

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl, asynchronous, zend-http-client

Is it possible to make asynchronous connections with Zend_Http? How?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you have against the documentation?

Comment: I have checked documentation, but I've found nothing

Comment: Do you want only reload something over ajax or do you want a permanent connection to a server?

Comment: I need async connections for my CLI php application. Now, I use MultiRequest class (http://code.google.com/p/multirequest/). But I thought that is something similar in Zend Framework.

Answer (score 2):

No. Zend_Http does neither support parallel requests (look into [curl_multi](http://php.net/curl_multi_init) for that) nor asynchronous requests or response polling. All adapters are ->read right after the request ->write.

Comment: Yes, Without getting exotic (and possibly daft), curl_multi is about the only easy way to this. There some old (but still correct) tutorials about the basics of how to do this.
http://www.paul-norman.co.uk/2009/06/asynchronous-curl-requests/

Comment: @JamesButler: There is also a newfangled way to do it: http://php.net/httprequestpool - And it would be (here comes a overly hypothetical assumption) possible to build something yourself using a fsockopen pool. But in PHP it's hard to make it either efficient or really asynchronous.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that. I'm guessing its a wrapper/abstraction over curl. Everyday is a school day!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, though an not a natural solution, but ...

```
try {
    $result = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    //no hadle
}
```

and provide timeout value of 1

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client("http://127.0.0.1:80......."", array(
    'timeout'      => 1
));
```